# why are C7 and Cmaj7 different chords

Tags: jazz

I'm relatively new to music theory, I was under the impression Cmaj7 was the same as C7 so i just added a minor third above the C triad (CEG) and got CEGBb.
As it turns out, C maj7 is actually a major third above the C triad - that is CEGB.

Then there's the Cminor variation, that is C Eb G, and Cminor7 C Eb G Bb.
If there is a discrepancy within the chords and the 7th why is there no discrepancy between regular C and C major?

Answer (score 1):

Several sevenths exist. The most used is probably C7 made up from CEGBb. It is a dominant. Next is Cmaj7. C E  G B. Then Cm7. C Eb G Bb. And dont forget Cm maj7. C Eb G B. They are all in common usage but C7 is more used so has the simplest, if not most explanatory name.

Answer (score -4):

The "maj" modifier is for the "7", not for the "C".  "major" is never indicated for the general mode of the chord (indicated by the third step): that's the default.  Only minor is indicated, with "m" or in the case of Jazz, "-".

There is really not much to be done here rather than learn all of the handful of exceptions and conventions.  There is not a lot of logic behind them.

Comment: Also I down voted due to your last paragraph.  There _is_ logic behind the conventions as dominant 7ths were dominant hence it make sense to refer to the most popular 7th as just 7.